# Installing JS code on Shopify or Website

Tags: javascript, shopify

thanks in advance.

I've created this JS function which is working on test websites but it not working on shopify.

How can i call it into a product page?
Probably there is some mistake in there

Thank you

```js
var output, started, duration, desired;

// Constants
duration = 5000;
desired = '50';

// Initial setup
output = $('#output');
started = new Date().getTime();

// Animate!
animationTimer = setInterval(function() {
    // If the value is what we want, stop animating
    // or if the duration has been exceeded, stop animating
    if (output.text().trim() === desired || new Date().getTime() - started > duration) {
        console.log('animating');
        // Generate a random string to use for the next animation step
        output.text('' + Math.floor(Math.random() *(50 - 25) + 25) 

        );

    } else {
        console.log('animating');
        // Generate a random string to use for the next animation step
        output.text('' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 25) + 25)

        );
    }
}, 4000);
```

```css
#output {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working"? I tested it on our shopify page and it worked. For the product page make sure you clicked the arrows on the top right bar for "Show HTML" to be able to enter code. Also enclose your JS in <script></script> if you did not.

Comment: Hello, Thx for your reply. I tried to copy this script in product-template.liquid bceause i need to see in any product page using this JS script and  <script></script>, i have also tried to use the arrows in the product page like you said, it is showing nothing, I need to see a number inside it, but nothing.

Comment: I hale also tried to create a new js file, but nothing work, maybe i miss some step. please help, what do you do to make it work? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I ran out of room in the comments if you click the arrows in the top right of your product page and copy and paste this code in and it'll work just fine.

If it is still not working the only other thing I can think of is maybe you don't have jquery included in your theme since your code uses jquery. To validate that your theme already has jquery go to theme.liquid <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>  'jquery'

If you find it, I am uncertain what problem you are having; if not add it to your theme and you test it again.

```
<div id="output"></div>
<script>// <![CDATA[
var output, started, duration, desired;

// Constants
duration = 5000;
desired = '50';

// Initial setup
output = $('#output');
started = new Date().getTime();

// Animate!
animationTimer = setInterval(function() {
    // If the value is what we want, stop animating
    // or if the duration has been exceeded, stop animating
    if (output.text().trim() === desired || new Date().getTime() - started > duration) {
        console.log('animating');
        // Generate a random string to use for the next animation step
        output.text('' + Math.floor(Math.random() *(50 - 25) + 25) 

        );

    } else {
        console.log('animating');
        // Generate a random string to use for the next animation step
        output.text('' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 25) + 25)

        );
    }
}, 4000);
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: If this solved your problem click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green to let others know that this issue is resolved.

Comment: unfortunately not yet, see above

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved it

I should install Jquery like this

{{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js' | script_tag }}

and not like this

etc.etc.